# Improve a server with select() function

Tags: c++, select, networking, client-server, multi-user

I read about select() and also read many examples of it, but I can't understand when can I use it?
I understood that I can use it in the accept() function, in case I want few people to connect to the server, but it has confused me.
I need to built a server that receive data only from 2 clients, 1 every time. The first user sends to the server a string, the string responds and then the second user sends a string.
Can someone help me with combining the select() function in the recv() function?
I've added my server.cpp code. Thank you!

server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define LIMIT 1

// server side 
#define INVALID_MOVE 00
#define PLEASE_ENTER_A_MOVE 15
#define PRINT_BOARD 20
#define END_GAME 30

// client side
#define MOVE 10


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    SOCKET clientsock[2];
    int minsock = 0;
    int numsocks = MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSA Initialization failed!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Socket creation failed.\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN serverInf;
    serverInf.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInf.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverInf.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)(&serverInf), sizeof(serverInf)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to bind socket!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    listen(serverSocket, 5);



    clientsock[0] = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Client 1 has connected." << endl;
    clientsock[1] = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Client 2 has connected." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Client " << i+1  << " Has Connected!" << endl;
    }

    char client1_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char client2_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* clientBuffer;
    // until there isn't a mate.
    bool gameRunning = true;
    // user represents if it's user1 (0), or user2(1)
    bool user = 0;


    while (gameRunning)
    {
        if (!user)
            clientBuffer = client1_buffer;
        else
            clientBuffer = client2_buffer;

        int in = recv(clientsock[user], clientBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        cout << in << endl;
        if (in > 0)
        {
                // CHECKS
                // MOVE COMMAND
                // IF worked, send the board to both clients. if current user = 1 ==> do user to 0 | if the user = 0 => do user to 11
                // ELSE, send the current client (clientsock[user]) Error message and ask for a command again.
                cout << clientBuffer << endl;
                cout << " IN RECV";
                char* szMessage = "15";
                send(clientsock[user], szMessage, sizeof(szMessage), 0);
        }
        else if (in == 0)
        {
            // The connection has closed.
            // REMEMBER : SAVE THE GAME SITUATION.
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            // SEND ERROR MESSAGE TO BOTH CLIENTS
        }

        user = !user;
    }
    // Shutdown our socket
    shutdown(serverSocket, SD_SEND);

    // Close our socket entirely
    closesocket(serverSocket);

    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you wrote your own server in C(++) and now want to add a function that you don't know of what it does, just for fun?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I know what it does, as I said I read a lot on this function. I just don't know how to combine it in my own code.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Can you help me instead of trying to emberess me?

Comment: @HansKlunder i have already fixed it, every iteration of the whole loop the socket changes.

Comment: stackoverflow allows you to edit your question. That has the advantage that people reading your question see the fixed version, not the outdated version that still talks to just one client.

Comment: @HansKlünder Done, I'll be glad for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that you corrected your code, I have to do some work.

I suggest you remove this

```
user = !user
```

and add this immediately after the beginning of the while loop:

```
{
   int nfds = 0;       // smallest number higher than all socket descriptors
   fd_set set;         // this contains garbage from the stack, thus ...
   FD_ZERO(&set);      // first clean it and then add both client sockets:
   FD_SET(clientsock[0],&set); if(nfds<=clientsock[0]) nfds=clientsock[0]+1;
   FD_SET(clientsock[1],&set); if(nfds<=clientsock[1]) nfds=clientsock[1]+1;
   select(nfds,&set,0,0,0); // this uses and changes the content of set
   bool next = !user;  // next is the other user, and we try to serve it:
   if(FD_ISSET(clientsock[next],&set)) user=next;
}
```

By the way, I like your creative way of using bool as an index, though once you have more than 2 clients, you might have to change that concept.

My code implements a little bit of scheduling policy: If there is data available from both clients, it reads from that client from which it did not read data the previous time. If, instead, you want to read lots of data from one client and then lots of data from the other, replace the lines containing `next` by

```
if(!FD_ISSET(clientsock[user],&set)) user=!user;
```

The first version tries to alternate as often as possible, while the second tries to read as much data as possible from the same client before switching to the other.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I still have a bit of misunderstanding, I'm trying to create a chess game - A user enters a command (i.e. E2-C5), then the server checks if this string is possible (chess rules) - and then, if it possible returns the board to both users, else it returns a Error message (through socket) to the user. Can you help me a little bit? 
I'm appreciate you help.

Comment: First, be careful - TCP sockets don't honor packet boundaries. Be sure you got a complete move from onc client before analyzing it. You might have to recv() several times for one move. This will happen rarely, but it can happen. Then - well, you got the move, you analyze it, and then, depending on whether it's valid, you can either send an error message to one client or a board change first to one client and then to the other.

Comment: I recieve a string from the clients in this format : XX-YY, so there shoudln't be any problems.  
I didn't understand how can I send to specific user a string, and how can I send to both clients? I read about read and write pointers, but I didn't understand much.

Comment: Well - you do it already: `send(clientsock[0],szMessage,sizeof(szMessage),0);` sends a reply to one user, and using `[1]` you can send it to the other.

Comment: So the code that you gave me is only for the accept function of some users?

Comment: It's intended to decide from which socket to read next. That's what select() does.

Comment: And I can also choose which socket write to?

Comment: Yes. You can use the 3rd parameter of select for that. This will tell you which socket you can write to, that is, an attempt to write would not block. But still, youself have to decide to whom you want to write at all.